# How to fix my XL motor?

Tags: power-functions, repair, motor

I used the XL motor near water. Now it stopped working. Can someone tell me what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Funny, I've heard some people claim that PF motors are actually quite resistant to water and even work when immersed, so maybe that's not the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to contact the LEGO customer service which will usually provide a replacement motor free of charge.

Comment: What?! Really? Are you serious? I should check to see if they'll replace my two busted motors! I thought if your Power Functions stop working you have to buy new ones yourself. I am definitely going to see what they've got to say.

Comment: I'v had my share of replaced dead motors, so yes, I'm pretty serious. In any case, the only think you can lose is a bit of your time, since in most countries their customer service uses a free number.

Answer (score 4):

It seems encased. You can try to open it up, expect a short happened internally.
Your best bet is to probably [buy](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/LEGO-Power-Functions-XL-Motor-8882) a new one. at 10$, it isn't so bad don`t you think?

Comment: For AFOLs, 10 bucks is not bad at all, but for kids, 10 dollars may well be a good amount of yearly income.